# Hiding comment title in theme wordpress

Tags: elementor

I use hello elementor theme and I would like to hide the name title, email title, and comment title and show them in the placeholder.  How can I do this?

[image: Screen shot of my user interface]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Contact Form 7, you can remove the label titles and set placeholder texts on each field using the CF7 form editor.

If you are using Elementor's Pro Form element, you can do the same procedure on the Elementor's Editor page while configuring the Form element.